# can you assign more than one value to an item in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

when you have something like

```
people = {'Sarah':'blonde'}
```

can you assign more than one value?

Comment: `people = {'Sarah':['blonde', 'brunette']}` ?

Comment: You can assign a list or rather a nested dictionary for example `people = {'sarah': {'gender': 'female', 'hair': 'blonde'}}`

Comment: Strictly speaking, no. But the single value can be a container which *contains* multiple values.

Comment: To follow-up on @chepner's comment, you can use the dictionary subclass [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which would allow you to just `append()` values to keys in the dictionary as shown in the example code in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list as value for key-value dictionary item:

```
people = {'Sarah': ['blonde', 'bald']}
```